# Alphabet to Number and Number to Alphabet

Tags: code-golf, string, number, alphabet

## Challenge

In this challenge you have to take a number as input and output the corresponding letter of the alphabet, and vice versa. (1 <=> A, 2 <=> B) etc.

```
1 -> A
2 -> B
...
26 -> Z

A -> 1
B -> 2
...
Z -> 26
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.
- The input will only consist of either an uppercase letter from `A` to `Z` or an integer from `1` to `26` inclusive.
- Trailing whitespaces (space and newline) are allowed.

Comment: "You can't create variable, just arrays, let and const." "100 -> 0" Is it ok now?

Comment: @Chad Can you just let invalid input be undefined? i.e. it can error or do anything? Basicially it can be assumed the input is valid.

Comment: If I have a statically typed language, can I input the numbers as a string?

Comment: Why duplicate? O.o It is not equal.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, of course.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This challenge could use a bit of clarification. For example, you could specify what inputs we would need to handle, since there are invalid inputs. I recommend posting future challenges to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where they can get meaningful feedback before being posted to the main site.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the valid inputs and outputs are.

Comment: Will we receive `26` as an integer or `"26"` as a string, or are both allowed?

Comment: Are we allowed leading newline?

Comment: Does it have to be uppercase, or is lowercase acceptable instead?

Comment: Seriously, another alphabet challenge? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @shooqie Why I can't?

Comment: Who will do a program with less of 7 Bytes,will exceed the current winner.

Comment: Is the output of number-to-letter conversion required to be uppercase as well?

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97859/encode-the-alphabet-cipher)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Actually, 7 bytes

```
ú' +ûEí
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7onICvDu0XDrQ&input=IkUi)

Explanation:

```
ú' +ûEí
ú' +     lowercase English alphabet, prepend space
    û    uppercase
     E   element (pushes the nth letter if input is an integer, leaves stack alone otherwise)
      í  index (pushes index of input if input is a string, leaves stack alone otherwise)
```

If lowercase is acceptable, this is 6 bytes:

```
ú' +Eí
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7onICtFw60&input=ImUi)

Comment: You're winning at the moment, I think nobody could do a program with less 7 bytes.

Comment: @Chad There easily could be a solution under 7 bytes.

Comment: I joined just to ask this. @Mego what language is this?

Comment: @FoldedChromatin looks like https://github.com/Mego/Seriously

Comment: @FoldedChromatin Actually, it's `Actually`. Hence `Actually, 7 bytes`. :P

Comment: Moments like these make me happy about the names I chose for my languages :)

Comment: I just realized `Actually` is the **in-place** successor to `Seriously`. I assumed the latter was someone else's project which inspired yours. The GitHub URL makes it all the more clear?/confusing?

Comment: @Dan The confusing names are intentional. Seriously is both the name of the project *and* the name of the first version. Actually is the name of Seriously v2. Seriously v3 will have a separate name, as well as being Actually v2.

Comment: @Mego Lmao. The rolling versions, multiple names scheme is hysterical.

Answer (score 11):

## Pure Bash, 51

Most of the rest of the answers use some sort of conditional.  This one dispenses with conditionals entirely, and instead treats the input as a base-36 number which indexes into an appropriately constructed bash-brace-expansion array:

```
a=(_ {A..I} {1..26} {J..Z} {A..Z})
echo ${a[36#$1]}
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/zFW3J7)

Comment: So what does the `#` do?

Comment: @R.Kap *"[numbers take the form \[base#\]n, where the optional base is a decimal number](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)"*.

Answer (score 9):

## Erlang, 26 bytes

```
f([X])->X-64;f(X)->[X+64].
```

One of the few times where Erlang's string behavior is useful.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 38 bytes

```python
lambda x:x>''and 64^ord(x)or chr(64^x)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/E9pcsJ).

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 43 bytes

```python
lambda x:x!=str(x)and chr(64|x)or ord(x)^64
```

The interesting thing about this solution is that it incorporates all the senses of OR, bitwise OR `|`, logical OR `or`, bitwise XOR `^` and logical XOR `!=` ...

Answer (score 6):

## [2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Code:

```
.bAu¹kr,
```

Explanation:

```
.b        # Convert 1 -> A, 2 -> B, etc.
  A       # Push the alphabet.
   u      # Convert it to uppercase.
    ¹k    # Find the index of the letter in the alphabet.
      r   # Reverse the stack.
       ,  # Pop and print with a newline.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=LmJBdcK5a3Is&input=Rw).

Comment: Can't you delete ,? Which bytes are without ,? You don't need to print a new line.

Comment: @Chad Nope, that won't work for numeric inputs :(

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <s>47 39 + `n` flag = 40 bytes</s> <s>33</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes

Anonymous function. Uses an exception handling trick like in @KarlNapf's [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89968/52194).

-3 bytes from @manatwork

[Try it online](https://repl.it/Cn5s)

```
->i{(64+i).chr rescue i.ord-64}
```

Original full program version with the `n` flag for 40 bytes and reads from STDIN:

```
puts$_!~/\d/?$_.ord-64:(64+$_.to_i).chr
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error when trying to [run on ideone](https://ideone.com/q6iS0v), can you tell how to test?

Comment: @Leibrug oops! It's fixed now

Comment: You can reduce it more by shamelessly applying [Karl Napf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53667/karl-napf)'s trick from his [Python solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89968): `->i{(64+i).chr rescue i.ord-64}`.

Answer (score 5):

## Cheddar, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*

```
n->"%s"%n==n?n.ord()-64:@"(n+64)
```

I wish there was shorter way to check if string or number.

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=bi0-IiVzIiVuPT1uP24ub3JkKCktNjQ6QCIobis2NCk&input=MQ) or 
[Test Suite](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=bGV0IGY9IG4tPiIlcyIlbj09bj9uLm9yZCgpLTY0OkAiKG4rNjQpOwpwcmludCBmKDEpOwpwcmludCBmKDI2KTsKcHJpbnQgZigiQSIpOwpwcmludCBmKCJaIik7&input=)

### Explanation

```
n ->                // func with arg `n`
    "%s"%n==n ?     // if n is string... (see below)
       n.ord() - 64  // return code point - 64
    :               // else...
    @"(n+64)         // chr(n+64)
```

`"%s"%n==n` checks if it is a string in a simple way. `"%s"` is a string format, I can format with `%` e.g. `"a %s c" % "b"` is equal to `"a b c"`. `%s` specifies it is a string, if a digit is passed it'll remain as `%s`.

Comment: `"%s"%n==n` saves 2 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun oh that's smart! I was tryomg of doing `"%d"%n==n` but that wasn't working :/

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <s>54</s> 41 Bytes

With an absolutely clever suggestion from LegionMammal978 that saves 13 bytes.

```
If[#>0,FromLetterNumber,,LetterNumber]@#&
```

`If[#>0,FromLetterNumber,,LetterNumber]` serves the sole purpose of deciding whether to apply `FromLetterNumber` or `LetterNumber` to the input.

`#>0` will be satisfied if the input, `#`, is a number, in which case `FromLetterNumber`will be selected.

However `#>0` will be neither true nor false if `#` is a letter, and `LetterNumber` will be selected instead.

---

```
If[#>0,FromLetterNumber,,LetterNumber]@#&["d"]
```

4

---

```
If[#>0,FromLetterNumber,,LetterNumber]@#&[4]
```

d

---

In Mathematica, `FromLetterNumber` and `LetterNumber` will also work with other alphabets.  This requires only a few more bytes.

```
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[4, "Greek"]
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[4, "Russian"]
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[4, "Romanian"]
```

δ
г
b

```
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[δ, "Greek"]
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[г, "Russian"]
If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, , LetterNumber][#, #2] &[b, "Romanian"]
```

4
4
4

Comment: Some golfing, bringing it to 41 bytes: `If[#>0,FromLetterNumber,,LetterNumber]@#&`

Comment: I interpret your suggestion as: `If[#>0,FromLetterNumber[#],LetterNumber@#]‌&`.  Although `If[#>0,FromLetterNumber[#],LetterNumber@#]‌&[4]` works, `If[#>0,FromLetterNumber[#],LetterNumber@#]‌&["c"]` does not. It apparently cannot resolve `"c">0`. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: The double `,,` is intentional, and so is the exterior `@#`; it evaluates as `If[# > 0, FromLetterNumber, Null, LetterNumber][#]&`, which uses the 4-argument form of `If` (look it up).

Comment: Amazing how the 4-argument form of `If` works.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 54 bytes

```
f s|s<"A"=[['@'..]!!read s]|1<2=show$fromEnum(s!!0)-64
```

Usage example: `map f ["1","26","A","Z"]` -> `["A","Z","1","26"]`.

Haskell's strict type system is a real pain here. Additionally all the short char <-> int functions like `chr` and `ord` need an import, so I have to do it by hand. For the letter -> int case, for example I need to convert `String` -> `Char` (via `!!0`) -> `Integer` (via `fromEnum`) -> `String` (via `show`).

Answer (score 4):

## C, 55 bytes

```
i;f(char*s){i=atol(s);printf(i?"%c":"%d",64^(i?i:*s));}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{+$_??chr $_+64!!.ord-64}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter of ｢$_｣
{
    +$_         # is the input numeric
  ??
    chr $_ + 64 # if it is add 64 and get the character
  !!
    $_.ord - 64 # otherwise get the ordinal and subtract 64
}
```

### Example:

```perl6
say ('A'..'Z').map: {+$_??chr $_+64!!.ord-64}
# (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26)

say (1..26).map: {+$_??chr $_+64!!.ord-64}
# (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
```

Comment: Even though the syntax is so different, that same mechanism is the same number of bytes in Perl 5: `perl -pe '$_=/\d/?chr$_+64:-64+ord'`!

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 32 bytes

```
n=>(n^=64)>26?(object)(char)n:n;
```

Casts to `Func<int, object>`.

Input: `char` implicitely converts to `int` so can be called with `int` (1-26) or `char` ('A'-Z').

Output: Either a `char` or `int`.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, <strike>49</strike> <strike>41</strike> 40 bytes

```
<?=+($i=$argv[1])?chr($i+64):ord($i)-64;
```

I do not think there is a good alternative to `is_numeric` right?

This is executed from command line (`$argv[1]` is the first variable given)

### Thanks to:

@insertusernamehere: Golfed 8 bytes. Replacing `is_numeric($i=$argv[1])` with `0<($i=$argv[1])`.This works because `(int)"randomLetter" == 0`.

@manatwork: Reduced with 1 byte. Replace `0<` with `+`. What happens in this case is that the + signal will cast the "Z" (or whatever letter) to an 0. This will result in false. Therefor any letter is always false and a number is always true.

Comment: Using `0<($i=$argv[1])` instead of `is_numeric($i=$argv[1])` saves you *8 bytes*.

Comment: Continuing on that idea: `0<` → `+`.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 33 bytes

```
=IFERROR(CHAR(A1+64),CODE(A1)-64)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 61 bytes

```python
i=raw_input()
try:o=chr(int(i)+64)
except:o=ord(i)-64
print o
```

Yes I could switch to Python 3 for `input`

Comment: Use `input()` nevertheless and change `int(i)` to `i`.

Comment: Then character inputs don't work.

Comment: Take input as `"A"`

Comment: That's lame. `A` or nothing.

Comment: You could knock a few bytes off by reformulating it as a function: line 1: `def f(i):`, line 2: <space> `try:o=chr(i+64)`, line 3 <space> otherwise unchanged, line 4: <space> `return o`  In that form, it would work in either Python 2 or Python 3

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>104</s> <s>98</s> <s>97</s> <s>83</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 30 bytes

`x->(x^=64)>64?(char)x+"":x+"";`

**Test Program**:

```
IntFunction<String> f = x -> (x ^= 64) > 64 ? (char) x + "" : x + "";
out.println(f.apply('A')); // 1
out.println(f.apply('Z')); // 26
out.println((f.apply(1))); // A
out.println((f.apply(26))); //Z
```

Comment: You can drop about 20 bytes by using a ternary operator like so: `return(s.matches("\\d+")?(char)(Integer.parseInt(s)+64)+"":(s.charAt(0)-64)+"");`

Comment: you can remove casting to int as well, which allows you yo reduce by 7 bytes.

Comment: The program does not take any input. The program does not give any output. There even is no program!

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco You are not required to write a full program unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

### [Befunge 93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), <strike>144 90 66 54  36</strike> 19 bytes

Not 100% sure if this is allowed, but if you are allowed to type A as 65, B as 66, etc., then (for [my] convenience's sake):

```
&:"@"`"@"\#. #-_+,@
```

Otherwise, at 36 bytes:

```
~:0\"A"-`#v_88*-.@
**~28*++,@>68*-52
```

(Thanks to tngreene for the suggestions!)

```
~:0\567+*-`#v_88*-.>$28*+,@
52**\28*++,@>~:0`!#^_\68*-
```

(Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 12 bytes by rearranging!)

```
~:0\567+*-`#v_88*-.>$82*+,@
            >~:0`!#^_\68*-52**\28*++,@


v                   >$28*+,@
             >~:0`!#^_\68*-52**\28*++,@
>~:0\567+*-`#^_88*-.@


v                    >$28*+,@
~           >11g~:0`!|
1                    >\68*-52**\28*++,@
1
p           
>011g567+*-`|
            >11g88*-.@
```

Ungolfed:

```
v                       >$ 28* + , @
                 >~:0 `!|
                        >\ 68* - 52* * \ 28* + + , @
>~:0\ 5 67+ * - `|
                 >88* - . @
```

This is my first working Befunge program ever, and I feel the need to golf this further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can test Befunge code [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).

Comment: Passing quick glance comment: Befunge wraps around, so you can move the last 12 chars of the second line to the front and get `52**\28*++,@>~:0\`!#^_\68*-`

Comment: @Sp3000, oh I did't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations on your first program ever! One thing to consider would be to generate large numbers by pushing ASCII values in a string. Compare `567+*` to `"A"`. Also, don't forget about `g` and `p` instructions for reusing a value instead of having to build it up repeatedly.

Also, I couldn't find any input that would take the IP to the branch `>$ 28* + , @`. What is this for? Are you sure its needed?

Comment: Lastly, I admire your dedication to parsing "26" or "08". Your method, as I read it, involves much symbol<->number conversion math, as in ('2' to 2 back to '2'). Having your first and second inputs as numbers before you start comparing them could decrease the amount of ASCII-arithmetic you're doing. Alternatively, maybe there is a way to efficiently deal with inputs as symbols ('2' as in '2'), no conversion to numbers needed!

Comment: @tngreene, Integer inputs <10 go to the branch `$28*+,@` whereas  those >=10 go to the other one. This was done ultimately because you cannot read over the input more than once as far as I know.

Comment: I tried running it, and even putting in "09" it still went to the same branch as "10", golfed and un-golfed.

Comment: @tngreene, yeah because I assumed (falsely?) that 09 is invalid input and must be 9

Comment: @Dopapp Welp, if you want to remove that branch, I'd think you'd be well within the problem spec.

Comment: @tngreene, wow, that saved almost 20 bytes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44130/discussion-between-tngreene-and-dopapp).

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 42 bytes

```
param($n)([char](64+$n),(+$n-64))[$n-ge65]
```

Takes input `$n` (as an integer or an explicit char) and uses a pseudo-ternary to choose between two elements of an array. The conditional is `$n-ge65` (i.e., is the input ASCII `A` or greater). If so, we simply cast the input as an int and subtract `64`. Otherwise, we add `64` to the input integer, and cast it as a `[char]`. In either case, the result is left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.

### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> ([char[]](65..90)|%{.\alphabet-to-number.ps1 $_})-join','
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> (1..26|%{.\alphabet-to-number.ps1 $_})-join','
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown)*, 19 bytes

```
&:39*\`'@\j;+,@;-.@
```

Because the question said you'll receive a `1-26` or an `A-Z` I assumed this meant the number 26 or the character A-Z. Most interprets struggle with entering alt-codes, so it is easier to use `&` and enter values like 26 for 26 or 90 for 'Z', as opposed to `~`.

### Pseudo-code

```
int c = get stdin
push the value of 27
bool is_number =  27 > c
push the value of `@` (64)
if is_number == 1
   jump to adding 64 to c //putting it the ASCII range
   print as ASCII
   end
else
   jump to subtracting 64 from c //putting it in the numerical range
   print as number
   end
```

Test it out (on Windows) [here!](https://github.com/tngreene/BefungeSharp)

*This is technically Unefunge-98 because it only uses 1 dimension, but that name might be unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 445 Characters

More a proof of concept than a golfed code.
Requires Unsigned, Non-wrapping Brainfuck.

```
,[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>>++[->++++++<]>[-<<<+++++>>>]<<<<[->-<]>[,<++++[->------------<]++++[->>------------<<][-<<++++++++++>>]>[-<+>]>[-<<++++++++++>>]>++[->++++++<]>+[-<+++++>]<-[-<<<+>>>]<<<.>]>[[-<+<+>>]>++[->++++++<]>+[-<+++++>]<-[-<<->>]<<[->+>+<<]>>>++++++++++<+[>[->+>+<<]>[-<<-[>]>>>[<[-<->]<[>]>>[[-]>>+<]>-<]<<]>>>+<<[-<<+>>]<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<-[->+>+<<]>[-<++++++++++>]<[-<->]++++[-<++++++++++++>]++++[->>++++++++++++<<]>>.<<<.>]
```

With Comments

```
,[>+>+<<-] Firstly Duplicate it across two buffers
>[<+>-] Move the second buffer back to the first buffer
>>++[->++++++<]>[-<<<+++++>>>] Establish 60 in the second buffer
<<<<
Compare Buffers 1 and 2
[->-<]
>
[ If there's still data in buffer 2
, Write the value in the units column to buffer two
<
++++
[->------------<] Subtract 12 from the units buffer
++++
[->>------------<<] Subtract 12 from the tens buffer
[-<<++++++++++>>] Multiply buffer three by ten into buffer 1
>
[-<+>] Add the units
>
[-<<++++++++++>>] Add the tens
>++ Add 65 to the buffer
[->++++++<]>+
[-<+++++>]
<- Actually we need 64 because A is 1
[-<<<+>>>] Add 64 to the first buffer
<<<
. Print the new letter
> Move to blank buffer
]
>
[ Otherwise we're a letter
[-<+<+>>] Copy it back over the first two buffers
>++ Write 64 to the buffer
[->++++++<]>+
[-<+++++>]
<-
[-<<->>] Subtract 64 from the letter
<<[->+>+<<]
>>>++++++++++< Copy pasted Division step x = current buffer y = 10 rest of the buffers are conveniently blank

+
[>[->+>+<<]>[-<<-[>]>>>[<[-<->]<[>]>>[[-]>>+<]>-<]<<]>>>+<<[-<<+>>]<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<
-
[->+>+<<]
>[-<++++++++++>]
<[-<->]
++++
[-<++++++++++++>]
++++
[->>++++++++++++<<]
>>.<<<.>
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤?UdI:InUc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pD9VZEk6SW5VYw&input=WzgsIkgiXS1tUw)

```
¤?UdI:InUc     :Implicit input of integer or string U
¤              :Convert to binary string if integer (always truthy)
¤              :Slice off first 2 character if string (always falsey)
 ?             :If truthy
  Ud           :  Get character at codepoint U
    I          :  After first adding 64
     :         :Else
      In       :  Subtract 64 from
        Uc     :  Codepoint of U
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 67 bytes

```forth
: f 2dup s>number? if d>s 64 + emit else 2drop d>s c@ 64 - . then ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/dTgIxEIXveYrjcoHGXSIbgomYVV7DhYvSnUKTbqdpuyK@PLaAwTt7M3/nzDdV7OO@2qkcTqcXKNTd4BAaO/Rb8m/QCl0TsJjjEdTrCDKBksizOw/ke55VmCLuyWKZdrjLjnh0hJzUaSy2AcEJSQHTAqgaFIklPZZYw3ltI7R1Q8S9IRUrYfTOUpd6FxdYIejvBH4or/KiaorfnIeYvUmkSig2hg/JvD3C0sFoS6NR/YwZ2o43aPUGT3gdYxwwbtKxrWF2G6S3Rk6hPPdJHRn1ooRk@0k@n9fRV26GmJi7hBYhXIvcVoOVUbMdTVpMVjeWEx3k3TnMbrS/qFW2f5RpF3uC3AsvZCSfPx@pd@yFP/5HPf0A)

Input is passed as a string to the function

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f             \ start a new word definition
  2dup          \ make a copy of the input string
  s>number?     \ attempt to convert to a number in base 10
  if            \ check if successful
    d>s         \ drop a number (don't need double-precision)
    64 + emit   \ add to 64 and output the ascii letter at that value
  else          \ if not successful (input was a letter)
    2drop d>s   \ get rid of garbage number conversion result and string-length
    c@ 64 - .   \ get ascii value of char, subtract 64 and output 
  then          \ end the if block
;               \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
i@ịe?ØA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/T4eHu7lT7wzMc/7sdbn/UtCby/39DHQVTHQUjEDbTUVByVAISHiAiEEREKQEA)

### How it works

```
i@ịe?ØA - Main link. Takes an input A on the left
     ØA - Set the right argument to "ABC...XYZ"
    ?   - If statement:
   e    -   Condition: left in right; is A in the alphabet?
i@      -   If so: return the 1-index of A in the alphabet
  ị     -   Else: yield the A'th element of the alphabet
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <sup><s>[27](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/259112/1)</s> <s>[24](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/259112/2)</s></sup> <sup><s>[21](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/259112/3)</s></sup> 19 bytes

```
<o+v?)0-}:"@":
n-$<
```

[Try it with a number test case](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiPG8rdj8pMC19OlwiQFwiOlxubi0kPCIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiIyNiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

[Try it with a letter test case](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiPG8rdj8pMC19OlwiQFwiOlxubi0kPCIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiJBIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Takes input on the stack, which is [a default input method for stack-based languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/114970), and outputs with error.

Comment: Happy to see others use my interpreter

Answer (score 2):

## q, 29 bytes

```
{@[1+.Q.A?;x;{.Q.A y-1}[;x]]}
```

Find the index at which our letter occurs in the built-in list of uppercase letters

If it errors, index into the same list with the input instead

Adding and taking away ones as q indexing starts at 0, not 1

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: And nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 30 bytes

```
I~F<64{1}{F+64a}F>64{1}{F-64o}
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SX5GPDY0ezF9e0YrNjRhfUY-NjR7MX17Ri02NG99&input=RQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>49 48 53</s> 50 bytes

Somehow I got the byte count wrong ;_;
thanks dahuglenny

`isalpha` is shorter than `isnumeric`

```
lambda x:x.isalpha()and ord(x)-64or chr(int(x)+64)
```

takes input as string, which could be a letter or number

Comment: You can remove the space between `x.isnumeric()` and `else` to save one byte.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

```
s=>s>0?String.fromCharCode(s|64):parseInt(s,36)-9
```

Accepts integers in either number or string format, always return integers as a number. 42 bytes if I can return lower case and don't need to handle integers in string format:

```
s=>s>0?(s+9).toString(36):parseInt(s,36)-9
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 73 bytes

```
f=function(x){L=LETTERS;if(is.numeric(x)){i=L[(x)]}else{i=which(L==x)};i}
```

Comment: No need for `f=`, and you cloud try to use the `ifelse` function to maybe golf out some bytes !

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript <s>86</s> <s>77</s> <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```
i=>typeof i<'s'?String.fromCharCode(i+64):i.charCodeAt(0)-64
```

- *saved 7 bytes after comments about using arrow functions*
- *saved another 11 bytes by removing return / brackets  as noted by @manatwork*
- *saved another 6 bytes thanks to @manatwork*

Comment: Use arrow functions

Comment: @BaldBantha cheers, changed it :-)

Comment: No need for `return` statement: `i=>typeof i=='number'?String.fromCharCode(i+64):i.charCodeAt(0)-64`.

Comment: @manatwork Cheers!

Comment: According to task description the `typeof` input can be only "number" or "string". So no need to check for `=='number'`, `<'s'` will also do it.

Comment: @manatwork that's a neat trick, thanks :)

Comment: `x=>-x?(9+x).toString(36):parseInt(x,36)-9`, 41 bytes

Comment: @user2428118 might be worth posting that as an answer ;-)

Comment: @Dylan [Done](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90152/13486). ☺️

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 10 bytes

```
6WZ~t42>?c
```

Explanation:

```
6W              % 2**6 = 64, but golfier looking
  Z~            % bit-wise XOR with input
    t42>?       % if result is greater than 42
         c      % convert it to a character 
                % else, don't
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NldafnQ0Mj4_Yw&input=WzE6MjZd) with numeric inputs.
[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NldafnQ0Mj4_Yw&input=WydBJzonWidd) with alphabetic inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**ASM: 10 bytes**

```
3C 40 77 04 2C 40 EB 02 04 40
```

Explanation:
This is the assembled representation of a program that does exactly what is asked. It is not fully functional, because it needs some directives, but if it is added to the code segment of an assembly program it should work. It receives the input in the AL register, and if its a letter it subtracts 40h from the ASCII code value, leaving just the number(i.e B=42h, 42h-40h=2h). If the input is a number it does the opposite procedure by adding 40h. It leaves the result in the AL register. Below is the assembly source code

```
cmp al,40h
ja letter_to_number
sub al,40h
jmp continue
letter_to_number: add ax,40h
continue:
```

Also,  if you convert all the other answers to machine code, I am positive that mine would be the smallest.

Comment: I think there are a few issues: `77 02 2C` should be `77 **04** 2C`; the `sub` and `add` are backwards.

Comment: I applied the above corrections and created a "function" that you can call from a C program on an x86_64 machine. `#define F(x) ((int(*)(int))"\x89\xf8\x3c\x40\x76\4\x2c\x40\xeb\2\4\x40\xc3")(x)`

Comment: What type of assembly is this?

Comment: Turbo Assembler

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 61 bytes

```
int f(char c){return c^64;}char f(int i){return(char)(i^64);}
```

Ungolf'd:

```
int f(char c) {
    return c^64;
}

char f(int i) {
    return (char) (i^64);
}
```

Calling `f('A')` invokes the first function, retuning an `int` 1;  calling `f(1)` invokes the second function, returning the `char` "A".

Comment: ` you have to take a number as input and output the corresponding letter of the alphabet, and vice versa. (1 <=> A, 2 <=> B) etc.` I don't think a set of functions qualifies for this.

Comment: @SeanBean it's a function overload.

Comment: That takes no input. That gives no output. There is no program!

Comment: You should assume the input is either "A".."Z" or "0".."9". Since a string is the only primitive that can hold either (you don't know what the input it going to be) your function should expect a string argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
;.L∧Ṇi₁pL∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvZPZo/rJHTY3WD3cteLh76cOt0x/u2gkkk6vLlRR07RSUyu0ftW141NT0cFdn7cOtE/5b6/k86lj@cGdbJlBXAYj9/z8A)

The core of this is [only 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvZPZo/rJHTY3WD3cteLh76cOt0x/u2gkkk6vLlRR07RSUyu2t/esetW141NT0qGO5/8NdnbUPt074/3BnWyZQW8H//wA), but the I/O for that version is a bit less than sane.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
di.bëÇ64-
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/JVMv6fDqw@1mJrr//7sCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/a/kVpSfa6WgZO9YGvyoqcnn0GpbLqWQfCsFBaDYua0u/1My9ZIOrz7cbmai@7@2Vuc/AA).

Also works in the new version of 05AB1E instead of the legacy, but the `Ç` wraps in a list: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/JVMv6fDqw@1mJrr//7sCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/kVpSfa6WgZO9YGvyoqcnn0GpbLqWQfCsFBaDYua0u/1My9ZIOrz7cbmai@7@2Vuc/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
di      # Legacy 05AB1E version: If the (implicit) input is an integer:
        # New 05AB1E version: If the (implicit) input is a positive (>= 0) integer:
  .b    #  Builtin to convert the integer to its 1-based uppercase alphabetic letter
 ë      # Else:
  Ç     #  Get the codepoint of the uppercase letter
   64-  #  And subtract 64 to convert it to its 1-based index
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>12</s> 4 bytes

```
øAɾt
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuEHJvnQiLCIiLCJCIl0=)

- -8 thanks to @lyxal

##### Explanation

Of course there's a built-in

```python
øAɾt # Implicit input
øA   # Letter to number or number to letter
  ɾ  # Range or uppercase (overloaded)
   t # Last item
```

Old:

```python
‹kA:?c[?ḟ›|i  # Implicit input
‹             # Decrement (no effect on strings)
 kA:          # Push uppercase alphabet and duplicate
    ?c        # Is the input alphabetic?
      [       # If it is:
       ?ḟ     #  Find the 0-based index of the input in the alphabet
         ›    #  And increment it to make it 1-based
          |   # Otherwise:
           i  #  Index input-1 into the alphabet
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuEHJvnQiLCIiLCJCIl0=) for 4 bytes

Comment: @lyxal nice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <sup><s>76</s> <s>53</s></sup> 50 bytes

```lua
x=...y=x:byte()print(64<y and y-64or x.char(x+64))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wlZPT6/StsIqqbIkVUOzoCgzr0TDzMSmUiExL0WhUtfMJL9IoUIvOSOxSKNC28xEU/P///9RAA)

## Explanation

```lua
x=... -- unpack command line arguments into x
y=x:byte()
print(
64<y -- if the first byte of the string > 64:
and y-64 -- print the first byte-64
or x.char(x+64) -- else, print chr(x+64)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
~a=a-'@'
~n::Int=n+'@'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7RNlFX3UGdqy7Pysozr8Q2TxvI@@9QnJFfrpCbWKBRp2NoZWSmyYUsou6obqUepa75HwA)

This solution involves a [single function with 2 methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/).

Answer (score 0):

## R, 75 bytes

```
f=function(l,a=which(LETTERS==l))ifelse(length(a),a,LETTERS[as.numeric(l)])
```

This function technically has two inputs. But the second one is merely there because by setting `a` through a default, I can get rid of 2 bytes. Give the function a quoted letter or number, or just a number, and it will return the opposite.

Explanation: `a` tests if it is a letter and which one it is. If it isn't it pulls the relevant letter.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

Code:

```python
lambda x:chr(x+64)if`x`[0]>"("else ord(x)-64
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
.xC+64sQhxr1G
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xC%2B64sQhxr1G&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22A%22%0A%22Z%22%0A1%0A26&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 53 characters

```
<K>=@sub{@char-int{$0};64}
<D>=@int-char{@add{$0;64}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<K>=@sub{@char-int{$0};64};<D>=@int-char{@add{$0;64}}' <<< 'M'
13

bash-4.3$ gema '<K>=@sub{@char-int{$0};64};<D>=@int-char{@add{$0;64}}' <<< '13'
M
```

Comment: This is the language every german hates

Comment: Uhm… Why? Google Translate gives no hint.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEMA_(German_organization)

Comment: Oh, I see. Probably mr. [David N. Gray](https://sourceforge.net/u/dngray/profile/) was not aware of this when created his macro language.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 62 Bytes

```
f=function(x)ifelse(is.finite(x),LETTERS[x],which(LETTERS==x))
```

Takes the input *x* and checks if it is finite, which is one byte shorter than checking if it is numeric and equivalent in this case. If yes, output the letter, if no, output the position in the alphabet equal to the character input.

Comment: Do you need `==1`? `is.finite` returns `logical`

Comment: `match(x,LETTERS)` is 3 bytes shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 14 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
{0::⎕A⍳⍵
⍵⊃⎕A}
```

`0::` if any error happens:
 `⎕A⍳⍵` return the index of the argument in the alphabet

`⍵⊃⎕A` use the argument to pick an element from the alphabet (errors if the argument is character)

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B0%3A%3A%u2395A%u2373%u2375%u22C4%u2375%u2283%u2395A%7D%20%u22C4%20f%A81%202%2026%20%27A%27%20%27B%27%20%27Z%27&run)

Answer (score 0):

## SQF, 72 bytes

Using the function-as-a-file format:

```
i=_this;if((str i)==i)then{toString[i+64]}else{((toArray i)select 0)-64}
```

Call as: `ARG call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Answer (score 0):

## q, 44 bytes

Reads from `stdin`

```
{$[0N~i:"J"$x;1+.Q.A?x 0;.Q.A i-1]}[read0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 41 bytes

```js
x=>-x?(9+x).toString(36):parseInt(x,36)-9
```

Comment: Actually I just noticed this answer is wrong. The input will be *uppercase*, it doesn't work then

Comment: @Dylan Fixed at the expense of three bytes.

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't give upper-case output yet. Not sure if that is also required though ;-) Nice answer though (y)

Comment: This is almost the same as my alternative answer, except for your `-x` golf.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 58 bytes

```
(if(char? i)(-(char->integer i)64)(integer->char(+ 64 i)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f i)
  (if (char? i)
      (-(char->integer i) 64)
      (integer->char (+ 64 i))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1)
(f 3)
(f #\A)
(f #\D)
```

Output:

```
#\A
#\C
1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DASH](https://github.com/molarmanful/DASH), 33 bytes

```
@[="num"type#0?fc +64#0?-(tc#0)64
```

Woo-hoo, first PPCG answer in my new functional programming language!

Installation and other info is all on the Github.

## Usage

```
(@[="num"type#0?fc +64#0?-(tc#0)64])"A"  #. strings
(@[="num"type#0?fc +64#0?-(tc#0)64])26   #. numbers
```

## Explanation

```
@                      #. lambda
  [                    #. start of conditional block
    = "num" (type #0)  #. check if argument is a number
      ? fc (+ 64 #0)   #. if so, add 64 to argument and convert from charcode
      ? - (tc #0) 64   #. otherwise, convert argument to charcode and subtract 64
                       #. we can actually leave off the closing bracket for now
```

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 68

Not a champion by any measure, but I had to do it.

```
puts [expr {[string is di $a]?[format %c [incr a 64]]:[scan $a %c]}]
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/VNCM94888)

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}1
"A"
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}2
"B"
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}26
"Z"
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}"A"
1
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}"B"
2
q){((?;@) -7=(@)x)[`,.Q.A]x}"Z"
26
```

**Explanation:**

Check the type of the input, if it's a `long` (-7h) then use the apply `@` operator to index into the alphabet `.Q.A`, otherwise use `?` to lookup the input in the alphabet. Note that we add null to the start of the alphabet to fake the 1-indexing:

```
{((?;@) -7h=type x)[`,.Q.A;x]} / ungolfed solution
{                            } / lambda function
                   [      ; ]  / apply a function to this
                    `,.Q.A     / join ` (null) to the string "ABC...XYZ"
                           x   / implicit input (e.g. "A" or 13)
 (                )            / do all this together
        -7h=type x             / is the type of parameter x a long (-7)
  (?;@)                        / ? (lookup) if true, @ (index) if false
```

**Notes:**

- -2 bytes by using indexing instead of switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

As unnamed generic lambda, accepting `char` or `int` and returning via reference parameter (input=output)

```cpp
[](auto&r){r+=r<64?64:-64;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1NCoMwEIX3OcVgoSrWRYu4aGJLr9HSRRhjG9AoMYIgnj2dWOi@m3lvft43OAz5C9HvtMF2qpXQ/eiskt2FMTm5HprKP55JsHubLjarrCiLa1mc87Lgq@eMTaM2LzCyU@MgUcHoappq46CT2iTpwqDpbYJvaQGhgvgWczKC3J1clmE4gRCYaY2cmiaZ06DYTw6EoAWV6AARBwYr@82VqVv@5Ye8pvyRkxD8VAa23tjb7wDX/8PZ6j8)

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/128/TheC64, VIC-20, PET) - <strike>90</strike> 48 (tokenized) bytes

```
 0inputa$:ifval(a$)>0then?chr$(64+val(a$)):end
 1?asc(a$)-64
```

Explanation and screen shot later.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
▄l!╧¿É$♦-É♦+$
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Dcu5DcJAFEXR/HXByBlC8v@2x3bIvu9izUiAwIiEEkhcAEg0AGUg4U7cyPCCc7N7OdzOp2t2dK583rNK@fj8vkXula93rcjZquecqRuYBjWpRW3qUJd61KcBDWlEY5rQlGY0pwUtaUVr2tCWdrQ3ECgChIhgESNBCvEhAlFIAAkhEcRCYkgCSaE@lI9CA2gIjaD2Dw)

**Explanation:**

```python
 l         # Push the input as string
  !        # Convert it to lowercase
    ¿      # If
▄          #    the lowercase alphabet
   ╧       #                           contains this value:
     É     #  Execute the following three operations:
      $    #   Convert the (implicit) input to its unicode value
       ♦-  #   Subtract 64
           # (Implicit else:)
     É     #  Execute the following three operations:
      ♦+   #   Add 64 
        $  #   And convert it to the character with this unicode value
           # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

This uses the [rule](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14275/24877) that wrapping the output in an optional type is allowed. We just use the standard `lookup` function to search in a list of tuples that define the input/output relationship.

```hs
(`lookup`zip(c++n)(n++c))
c=pure<$>['A'..'Z']
n=show<$>[1..26]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyMhJz8/u7QgoSqzQCNZWztPUyNPWztZU5Mr2bagtCjVRsUuWt1RXU9PPUo9livPtjgjvxwkZqinZ2QW@z83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSFNASinEK3kqKSjoOQMIoxAhKlS7P9/yWk5ienF/3UjnAMCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ö└╝╨→ε/óo↕[▄╢▐W
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=99c0bcd01aee2fa26f125bdcb6de57&i=A%0A1%0AZ%0A26&m=2)

This unpacks to the following 18 bytes:

```
cc%!{64+z+}{E64-}?
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=cc%25%21%7B64%2Bz%2B%7D%7BE64-%7D%3F&i=A%0A1%0AZ%0A26&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ä
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiw63LClOSi6GchcsMjSAsAA)

Overloaded built-in that works on both numbers (`1 -> A`, `2 -> B`, ...) and letters (`A -> 1`, `B -> 2`, ...).