# Encode the alphabet cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, number, alphabet, cipher

Given a string that contains only lowercase letters, encode that string with the alphabet cipher.

To encode with the alphabet cipher (I will be using the example `hello`):

1. First, convert each letter in the string to a number depending on its position in the alphabet (`a` = `1`, `b` = `2`, etc.) Example: `8` `5` `12` `12` `15`
2. Pad each number to two characters with `0`s. Example: `08` `05` `12` `12` `15`
3. Join. Example: `0805121215`

### Test cases

```
helloworld -> 08051212152315181204
codegolf -> 0315040507151206
alphabetcipher -> 0112160801020520030916080518
johncena -> 1015081403051401
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest number of bytes wins.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71735/substitute-numbers-by-their-respective-letter)

Answer (score 22):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

**Code:**

```
Ç4+€¦J
```

**Explanation:**

First, we convert the string to their ASCII values. `codegolf` would become:

```
[99, 111, 100, 101, 103, 111, 108, 102]
```

To get to the indices of the alphabet, you subtract `96`:

```
[3, 15, 4, 5, 7, 15, 12, 6]
```

To pad with zeros, add `100` to each element and remove the first character of each int. For the above example, `+100` would be:

```
[103, 115, 104, 105, 107, 115, 112, 106]
```

And removing the first character of each would lead to:

```
[03, 15, 04, 05, 07, 15, 12, 06]
```

We can merge both steps above (the `-96` and the `+100`) part to just `+4`. For the code:

```
Ç       # Convert to an array of ASCII code points
 4+     # Add four to each element in the array
   €¦   # Remove the first character of each element
     J  # Join to a single string
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4c0K-KCrMKmSg&input=Y29kZWdvbGY)

Comment: What does `¦` do again?

Comment: @carusocomputing Removes the first element of a string, list, etc.

Comment: Beyond genius...

Answer (score 14):

## Python 2, 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and`ord(s[0])+4`[1:]+f(s[1:])
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/p7RFlo).

Comment: Non recursive, same byte count: ``lambda s:''.join(`ord(x)+4`[1:]for x in s)``

Answer (score 9):

## C, <s>55</s> 43 bytes

```c
f(char*c){for(;*c;)printf("%02d",*c++-96);}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/SZPzoT)

Comment: `printf("%02d",*c++-96);}` is shorter and valid if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
FNwpt`+4CN
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23FNwpt%60%2B4CN%29%22&input=helloworld%0Acodegolf%0Aalphabetcipher%0Ajohncena&debug=0) My first go at Pyth.

```
FNwpt`+4CN
FNw         # For N in w (w is input, N will be single char)
   p        # Print without newline
        CN  # Int with code point `N`
      +4CN  # Add 4 to int with code point N
     `+4CN  # representation of above (basically to string)
    t`+4CN  # Tail (All but first character)
```

Python equivalent:

```py
for N in input():
    print(repr(ord(N) + 4)[1:], end='')
```

Comment: Good job on your first Pyth program!

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 46 bytes

```
lambda x:"".join("%02i"%(ord(j)-96)for j in x)
```

Pretty straightforward. [**Try it on repl.it!**](https://repl.it/EIwU/0)

Comment: Wow, two completely different attempts with the same byte count ;)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O+4ṾḊ$€
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Tys04bm-4biKJOKCrA&input=&args=aGVsbG8)**

#### How?

```
O+4ṾḊ$€ - Main link: s                                e.g. hello
O       - cast to ordinals                            e.g. [ 104,  101,  108,  108,  111]
 +4     - add 4                                       e.g. [  108,  109,  112,  112,  115]
     $€ - last two links as a monad for €ach
   Ṿ    -    uneval, effectively converts to strings  e.g. ["108","109","112","112","115"]
    Ḋ   -    dequeue, remove the leading '1'          e.g. [ "08", "09", "12", "12", "15"]
        - implicit print                              e.g. "0809121215"
```

Comment: I came up with `O+4DḊ€FṾ€` for the same count, perhaps golfable

Comment: @ETHproductions `O+4Ṿ€Ḋ€` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @Dennis I just did the same (ish)...

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>fortyfour 30</s> 28 bytes

```haskell
(>>=tail.show.(+4).fromEnum)
```

Using the `+4` approach from [Adnan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97864/56433) saves 14 bytes.

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/RzY4ET) Usage:

```haskell
> (>>=tail.show.(+4).fromEnum)"codegolf"
"0315040507151206"
```

Two bytes off thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor). Old version:

```haskell
f a=['0'|a<'k']++(show$fromEnum a-96)
(f=<<)
```

Comment: You don't need the second set of parens.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

```
f=s=>s&&(s.charCodeAt()+4+f(s.slice(1))).slice(1)
```

Recursion turned out to be 3 bytes shorter than `.replace`:

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,s=>(s.charCodeAt()+4+"").slice(1))
```

`parseInt(s,36)` is slightly longer for each approach, because you have to change `4` to `91`:

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,s=>(parseInt(s,36)+91+"").slice(1))
f=s=>s&&(parseInt(s[0],36)+91+f(s.slice(1))).slice(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 29 bytes

28 bytes of code + `-n` flag.

```pl
printf"%02s",-96+ord for/./g
```

Run with :

```
perl -ne 'printf"%02s",-96+ord for/./g' <<< "helloworld"
```

Comment: 25 bytes (or 27 under the rules at the time of this challenge): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1d1cCoWF3H0iwuvyhFIS2/yMHt//@M1Jyc/PLy/KKclH/5BSWZ@XnF/3XdAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 10 bytes

```
¡4+Xc)s s1
```

Probably doesn't get shorter than this...

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=oTQrWGMpcyBzMQ==&input=ImhlbGxvd29ybGQi)

### Explanation

```
¡           // Map each char X in the input by this function:
 4+Xc)      //   Take 4 + the char code of X.
      s s1  //   Convert to a string, then remove the first char.
            // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Luis*

```
4+!V4LZ)!le
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NCshVjRMWikhbGU&input=J2hlbGxvd29ybGQn)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7,60 bytes

```java
void f(char[]s){for(int i:s)System.out.printf("%02d",i-96);}
```

Comment: This answer might not be valid because it takes a `char[]` instead of a `String`.

Comment: @AlexL. [Lists of characters are considered strings.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/8478)

Comment: @MartinEnder Okay. Thank you for the clarification. This answer has my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 33 bytes

```
10}{'a({=!{{\.@29$\,<.-":!\>Oct\%
```

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=MTB9eydhKHs9IXt7XC5AMjkkXCw8Li0iOiFcPk9jdFwl&input=aGVsbG93b3JsZA)

Mm.. got a few no-ops in the Hexagon so I put today's date in.

### Expanded Form with date replaced by no-ops

```
   1 0 } {
  ' a ( { =
 ! { { \ . @
. . $ \ , < .
 - " : ! \ >
  . . . \ %
   . . . .
```

1. Initialise a `10` and move Memory Pointer to somewhere...
2. `$` skips the mirror and `,` reads a byte. `<` branches:
3. If end of string (`-1` which is non-positive) it goes to `@` and terminates the program.
4. Otherwise it subtracts `95` (decremented `a`), and then we print `result / 10` (integer division) and `result % 10` and loop again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
öÇIªÆ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=948049a692&i=%22helloworld%22%0A%22codegolf%22%0A%22alphabetcipher%22%0A%22johncena%22&a=1&m=2)

For each character

- add 4 to the codepoint e.g. `108`
- convert to string e.g. `"108"`
- drop the first character e.g. `"08"`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>19</s> 12 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
        ⎕UCS  ⍝ Convert the argument (string) into an array of codepoints.
      4+      ⍝ and add 4 to each of those codepoints.
     ¨        ⍝ Now, for each of those numbers
    ⍕         ⍝ turn it into a string
   ∘          ⍝ and
 1↓           ⍝ drop its first character.
∊             ⍝ Finally enlist the strings into a single string (as in, join them together)
```

Thanks @Bubbler for saving 7 bytes

### my original 19 bytes

```apl
{,/{1↓⍕⍵}¨4+⎕UCS ⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1pHv9rwUdvkR71TH/VurT20wkT7Ud/UUOdgBRD3f2pecn5K6qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iYClQUHOQPJEA/PYKhCBfXEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKKnUA)

```apl
{                   } ⍝ Define a function taking a string as argument.
             ⎕UCS ⍵  ⍝ Convert the argument (string) into an array of codepoints.
           4+         ⍝ and add 4 to each of those codepoints.
   {     }¨           ⍝ For each number in the array,
      ⍕⍵             ⍝ convert it to a string
    1↓                ⍝ and drop the first character (the 1).
 ,/                   ⍝ Finally join everything and return.
```

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9fraNfbfiobfKj3qmPerfWHlphov2ob2qoc7ACiMsFlNaASmsi5MBSQBksUppcjzq6cEqAhA@t0ADKIEn8h0o86piBIvE/NS85PyX1UduER719j7qaH/WuedS75dB640dtE4EqgoOcgWSIhydMoYJ6YlJySmpaekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZZU6AA). Check out the successive transformations to shorten the code.

Comment: @Bubbler thanks for the step-by-step! I'll read what those glyphs you introduced do, and then update my answer!

Comment: @Bubbler If I understand correctly, `∊` is acting as some sort of "flatten" right? Because I have a list of strings, i.e. a list of lists of characters, and then the `enlist` operator turns everything into a 1d array?

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 6 bytes

```
C4+ƛSḢ
```

*-1 byte thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiQzQrxptT4biiIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b3JsZCJd)

Explanation:

```
C       # Convert to ASCII codes
 4+     # Add 4
   ƛ    # On each number:
    S   #   Stringify
     Ḣ  #   Remove first char
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiQzQrxptT4biiIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b3JsZCJd) for 6 bytes.

Comment: @Steffan Cool approach, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 60 keystrokes

```
:s/./\=char2nr(submatch(0))-96."\r"/g
:%s/\<\d\n/0&
V{gJ
```

An *almost* entirely regex based solution. As usual, using the eval register makes it obscenely long.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>256</s> <s>239</s> 237 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set r=
set a=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
:g
set c=%a%
for /l %%i in (101,1,126)do call:l %%i
set s=%s:~1%
if not "%s%"=="" goto g
echo %r%
exit/b
:l
set i=%1
if %c:~,1%==%s:~,1% set r=%r%%i:~1%
set c=%c:~1%
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 58 Bytes

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)printf("%02d",ord($c)%32);
```

Comment: you can -8 bytes iterating as a string [50 bytes TIO](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VJJtVRKL0suiDWOjVTK1tWM1C4oy80rSNJRUDYxSlHTyi1KAajTVjA01rf///5@RmpOTX55flJMCAA), or -11 bytes input via `$argn` [47 bytes TIO](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VJJtVRKL0vOiVTK1tWM1C4oy80rSNJRUDYxSlHTyi1KACjTVjA01rf//z0jNyckvzy/KSfmXX1CSmZ9X/F/XDQA).

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 44 bytes

```
-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{"{0:D2}"-f($_%32)})
```

Takes input `$args[0]`, casts it as a `char`-array, feeds into a loop. Each iteration, we take the current character `$_` modulo `32`, which implicitly casts as the ASCII value. Conveniently ;-), this lines up so `a = 1, b = 2`, etc. That fed into the `-f`ormat operator, operating on string `"{0:D2}"`, which specifies a two digit minimum (i.e., it prepends a leading zero if required). Those strings of digits are encapsulated in parens, `-join`ed together into one string, and left on the pipeline. Output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program conclusion.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\encode-alphabet-cipher.ps1 'hello'
0805121215

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\encode-alphabet-cipher.ps1 'helloworld'
08051212152315181204

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\encode-alphabet-cipher.ps1 'codegolf'
0315040507151206

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\encode-alphabet-cipher.ps1 'johncena'
1015081403051401
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 24 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN:

```
encode.pl <<< hello
```

`encode.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/./substr 4+ord$&,1/eg
```

Comment: Nicely done. I think you probably meant `4+ord$&` instead of `5+ord$&` though ;-)

Comment: @Dada Right, pasted the version of my snippet buffer instead of the tested version again

Comment: It happens! :) Could I ask you an unrelated question? Do you have any idea what is the 8 bytes perl solution to this [question (reverse the input)](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Reverse+the+input) (on anarchy) ?

Comment: @Dada I'd say it is impossible in pure perl, so I expect it's some abuse of the automated system on that side. E.g. if input came from STDIN you could do `exec rev`

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thanks! I was having a hard time figuring this out since `print` is 5 bytes, `<>` is 2 more, so I was wondering what was the 1 byte builtin to reverse I hadn't heard of!

Answer (score 2):

## [DASH](https://github.com/molarmanful/DASH), 27 bytes

```
@><""(->@rstr["."""]+4#0)#0
```

Example usage:

```
(@><""(->@rstr["."""]+4#0)#0)"helloworld"
```

## Explanation

```
@ (                         #. take input through a lambda
  join "" (                 #. join with newlines the following:
    (map                    #. result of mapping
      @ (                   #. this lambda
        rstr ["." ; ""] (     #. replace first char w/ empty string:
          + 4 #0               #. mapped item's codepoint + 4
        )
      )
    ) #0                    #. over the argument
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## IBM PC DOS 8088 Assembly, <del>33</del> <del>28</del> 27 bytes

Assembled binary:

```
00000000: be82 00ac 2c60 7812 d40a 0530 3092 86f2  ....,`x....00...
00000010: b402 cd21 86f2 cd21 ebe9 c3              ...!...!...
```

Unassembled:

```
BE 0082     MOV  SI, 82H        ; point SI to command line string 
        CH_LOOP: 
AC          LODSB               ; load next char into AL
2C 60       SUB  AL, 'a'-1      ; convert ASCII to a=1,b=2...z=26 
78 12       JS   DONE           ; if char is terminator or not valid, exit
D4 0A       AAM                 ; convert binary to BCD 
05 3030     ADD  AX, '00'       ; convert BCD to ASCII 
92          XCHG DX, AX         ; save AX to DX for display 
86 F2       XCHG DH, DL         ; reverse bytes 
B4 02       MOV  AH, 2          ; DOS display char function 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; write first digit 
86 F2       XCHG DH, DL         ; reverse bytes back 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; write second digit 
EB E9       JMP  CH_LOOP        ; restart loop 
        DONE: 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

Standalone PC DOS executable.  Input string from command line, output to console.

I/O:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 44 bytes (2×22=44 codels)

```
tuuuumknnfbkqmkcalrmu_sajs?daltdddbfckkkkk ?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw1TtsKgzAM_Zc8RzBOnforKtLVuDq6tqhjD2P_vlRnTiDnwin9gPYjQ9O2KRZ_EGGNVwFdkHLh-WGRRCWWmEUpvOqxvUSrQjkVUnbk6c6OzfdHCmmfoDo2e4SVAzSQJAkg2PkpnNI4InnV0EzKrowwu_DaJDRsrX_7xY5D56TVufjzu7fTqZUNRt1403MwvJzuwxun2akBvj97yj8B)

Input the string with the [sentinel value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/24639#24639) `_`.

#### Pseudocode

```
while true:
  S = character input
  n = (codepoint of S) - 96
  if n+1 == 0:
    exit
  else:
    print(floor(n/10))
    print(n modulo 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 16 bytes

```
∾·(1↓•Fmt)¨4+-⟜@
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+wrcoMeKGk+KAokZtdCnCqDQrLeKfnEAKCkYgImFoZWxsbyI=)

#### Explanation

Same approach, independently derived, as [RGS's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201756/16766) and [tybocopperkettle's Vyxal `s` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250415/16766).

```
∾·(1↓•Fmt)¨4+-⟜@
             -⟜@  Subtract null byte from each character, giving its ASCII value
           4+      Add 4 (a = 101, z = 126)
  (      )¨        Map this function to each number:
     •Fmt            Format as string
   1↓                Drop first character
∾·                Join together into a single string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>25 22</sup> 15 bytes

```
[:,4}.@":@+3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcq9CsIwFAXgvU9xzeC1tA03aVLbC0JRcBIHVxGH/lgkEBDEQXz2GBRHOZzlnO8amhmrUzXjBjEREkdYMSDkQMCxhYTNYbcNR87NS7aC26yc3zmkyX4tIa5nvXhKwanIzOdJhm7yMAJOg3P@4W@ux@@GVJNVOsbqUllVK00GoeA/OhoyZGkZrabqJzvfDxfvRgxv)

*-7 bytes thanks to [ngn's K approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250555/15469)*

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
,/1_'$4+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwdjMEKAjEMRO/7GUXwoOAk26zVn5Haba0StssiePPbTSUwEObNK9fjiW77nT8Mg0OAENsJjyQUiOHdt7iaVdunbTo7g6yCh+BsCGPqQGpzfjQtvSbbT2YiMISBEZf/b76ORl1rvOd3eq41bzYgmC+QN1AsqUOvVpeUl+h++NUoXQ==)

`4+` add 4 to (the ASCII codes of) the argument - this turns `a` into 101, `b` into 102, etc

`$` format numbers as strings

`1_'` drop one digit from each

`,/` concatenate

Comment: Mind adding an explanation?

Comment: done            ⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭

Comment: Oh that’s clever!

Comment: not much different from other array-lang solutions, to be honest

Comment: Just saved me 7 bytes ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>45</s> 41 bytes

*-4 thanks Aiden*

```
;=xP W<1Lx;O++*'0'-2L=a-Ax 96a'\'=xSxF1""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltV9vKEf5s/4rFOVhaWU5kQXtubWQOyYUcTgnkQtJ8ADcIWcY6V5ZdSealhP71dGb2RSvbpE17@WBZu8/Mzjw7OzNrou5tFH1/lWRRuhzHe0U5Tuavp8OmOZImN7WhqHxcxCugPMlua0NlMhOYcTxJspilKUvn2S19NPXop9PPH1iver34dM786vVvB@dst3o9On3Hfqlezz@zXgU@OrkwsKefTwzo59MPBxd/tQvObPxos3/1/sT17MEFLCsmo2mYM4dXAiYKbNUqhkO2W82dHn7ByQwmyaNvDL/v7a1gcBnCoJuASVOOwBrm7dnZCYHwY5@c7KNvhiHn7wUA5A1b78J0GXN@mY14s0l@wK5cjoLz1uHZkf19EDx8ZF/2eicPg7NOx7E8q@ufBGH34IH95c@hdWUFDxcPR71W6zsHfGsgVDigIw5nLEBlg2YTVlyEeRHbnD01G0lWsmTQbMAore4yZ7LMIhgh4Qjey9nCLRbZpT8KnjzXewYdjQTUER6eHg68eYPqkwW7nyZlXCzCKG424Hsa2zAO4rYww2Wtq/Iqu5pc5ezp@XJk8/6rFidTGsmE2dragFmvLM6ECjW6BaNXGQx3OmIE7GzEaRGbA8/CnGgaR7@zyTxn2XJ2E@eFtIfZSTFObpNSaYXV0Z2eqz0ST4f1PNZhjrS80@Gsy4B0WAItTTjL43KZZ0zFixCjkBms2nAX5kl4k8bKCjAind/HuR3BesoQ9u0bU8ZF9BYREV8tLulJNrieBD0X9ijQwyvW4QmUkQqQbLxc2LilTHLaZfC2brDIB4XQJsy4sqzKppYlNg2EwQNtFAMlkD/gO1i2CIuSldMYlIV5CWC5AY5iFDc04uiJMtY4Vi8aC589ThvdqMgg8zF0y2SegdkYsd4ITIsUI8VysUDCuYoqNWLSb8Yf0G6QjTpUKC8yiGPIZRi50nLByidLH3gxcIQDmNf6mM/QTBVklAqFqzbajaaGaTqP7F3P7XF0EIe1E@RgtkzTMH80Ha3259zYno@WtowWlPLLbEWalujhEjIpbPL04PDtu@vftk5@PTMcNtXeJBv1@ut6t2qK3x9fvKCxjHNSGWZj9o9lqF5R7Z25xM76EoKA95bm4ngDFyS8WxeuY54pVebLDHdoIPOxU84LW@VKOgAQ2mUSMZq9WU4u/d2RtENsdJvSgzagWMCxKic2QMH/7TQdt1TeoXrkopJVBXAotAJR6cT6Ndwe6@3U/UTnMRb3WavMl3ELYlCPY0jC@CSEDIITLYysVkUC@om@y5JEdHx9O5@nMHNTZ@BFXyu3fuSQ8/MemWberJmZoo3ZH2ojBG05T1PbNNVlngsV4n8wOVszGavwh4OPpy7WYhFo8Hp82fM8D8IJXIFX9VYk/4y/lgwfAyNGDW@RAXhz8cOnz52gp0o6Zjis6vigT188dgBwdHxy6LAJJMdBQ4e2XA/TcBQu3DTOqAMwuFIdk@AMzt1LZKwKYm3C0oYFx06ol4BavEdcDKCoJDip80Y0W6zsAJGUjKoUgjQlI1ymuE/KaGo7wMxagwUcMfkXYZ2yDqw@w1UEIEBCsUWDLMzb5JRUL5vEWsjyAVXhCkGdaJlj6aJm9HLEn6owgwaKcrtY@BwWruvOIePZvO09TPCvQn4EJGgVHN3GZQp9pN2mvWzjDmGJHCcZHyQT26b9xIYgmuZoiwtxyrnY5sAbbLQVHpzaALHeoVhPdI6YDSQhA2UvkiRzZ2Xl28ofgdcz76oZlDQp1phrwGA0QPwFi/kizmxjYbeVt6hVAKuCmaiUEI@B7@3@QuOyubBFRzIB08foFLRwELIu9ncAh96B3nANWFqFlw2DrBNQK4QnFpBc0g16aC2iGjU4AfPNnqWisfLkN/AkfoA2Dk/7mp9btV2n68IWZrI14MlaeMAqaZ0XA/6r1Zd94oZA1plPVqDWKbXFNtYgrorQcLjLq8ZyLR0q0QtqDu3tAgXrh2FdGOiE1sdcFzIpb1VQNYHlJQ4zqfalEiZrlrkDMrdIFs4qFvBgiIsPkib2s0Yda7fpjtXtInQk2twrarcbyqzt104B9tjwxpk6arlh/rIs1O7rmBC9njCoow2iPAn5ElMyhpaxPaKbbtR3W1xYEQ19P1Ox5Is9x/6XDoPYAELhMJ7yQHnp882hGoWlesius9epaOLqO@ri0I269CxljpB@ddei04h2bNXr9gohp9qdDSyslucNPDhrPIh93cTCbINrDmECUwkJQA2yKUMG1hVc8hA06HZJnySKSubqRgtGy9rpf/NDYt5sJmb7h0Lbm4X@TmzWHBJXBxrzTS8HknbBesC6Pc0yYYH6Hpyzbg/OWM8E@z@J3oP0WMMGAUJp3b4a8RTlRLQ/9CTXPqd2xQmI/@bqgaBJcgXuCJRgscTAd7wyTOM8tgqWzaGHTtIyydh9@Ai8sfEc7qRlfBvnILOYZ3FWJiHeIuAkz9l9zKbhXQxAqQjhJZuF2RLC5/E1jqJ3N8g4UEFMFMu0xB8NaHGd8BSka2LUkiuUmXIasqIe9b2M9F42RMP2aiiP7udhirXxEbzOxmk8ZteV2ddayxN@E42ZsUjlzBCVdbvqnRO8IaGOYfqzzoN7FKwrhQ@TXi0vBvWsuM/Mw79nHgMU7cuf4tpMAPZZrVGkQZcZ2RB1eEJSlVxf1AHEbgVQbYwuaAiHEkNrPp732SyeRQsMs4wNr/f/X1eGf4ArQ@XK1gZfAumLdGX/ZfbFqhtMxul9VgP4GuGrArq1yc7qRbunMo@pQJvXrtIf@rKpNuybkjKVaPlv/428zEGGGi0/sPomutbmrmKDKuvWp3/6IqN62@omg7hG7TajUyFhUOMoqEkbaRIlENHpaDFh8hdwT/zqZTaaNe@Y2btIseN6145QQ37f7@8YtLwXV4bA6LA6ZgFavyNl8uLh6rOwU2toLwTRK0oHqyXP31TydrjuA3wtvUuD/6EhQsPwiVsR6eZft0Nmb@SDh7hqp4dNEjUIIv7FJD0I0ZEnAVYfx5MQkiR4pjrMJIPJZEw/IoVRCWXK2o4s7DlxhLMXbrGoTNdA6AblDwmzMMmwWWVhfhu5pNRx4Psdx5@r6H6J/9mxPbKmfo17/j6NweH7eZ6O/w0)

Comment: Instead of `A GxF1` you can simply do `Ax`, because `ASCII` already returns the ascii value of the first character in the string.

Comment: Nice trick using `SxF1` instead of `Gx 1Lx`

Comment: @Steffan `SxF1""` and `Gx 1Lx` are the same bytecount and do the same thing, so it's just two different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I missed the `""` lol

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
96-OH&YA!1e
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTYtT0gmWUEhMWU&input=J2hlbGxvd29ybGQn)

```
         % Implicit input
96-      % Subtract 96. So 'a' becomes 1, 'b' becomes 2 etc
OH&YA    % Convert each number to 2 decimal digits. Gives a 2-column matrix
!1e      % Transpose and linearize into a row
         % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <s>53</s> 46 bytes

<s>`->s{s.chars.map{|c|(c.ord-96).to_s.rjust(2,?0)}.join}`</s>

`->s{s.chars.map{|c|(c.ord+4).to_s[1..2]}.join}`

Comment: 41 bytes: `->s{s.chars.map{|c|"#{c.ord+4}"[1,2]}*''}`

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>71</s> 51 bytes

Saved 20 bytes thanks to Billywob. Takes input from stdin and outputs to stdout.

```
cat(sprintf("%02d",utf8ToInt(scan(,""))-96),sep="")
```

Examples:

> helloworld -> 08051212152315181204
>
> codegolf -> 0315040507151206
>
> alphabetcipher -> 0112160801020520030916080518
>
> johncena -> 1015081403051401

Comment: You can use `utf8toInt(scan(,"))-96` instead of the whole match thing. Don't think there's a better way to handle the padding though.

Comment: @Billywob Thanks! For the padding, I tried using `formatC` earlier but that worked out as needing one more byte than the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Labyrinth, 40 bytes

```
      ,")@
!{_10%! (
/       _
01_}:-69"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

Using the neat algorithm in [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97864/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=TzQrYCRwWGBNzqM&input=ImpvaG5jZW5hIg)

```
O4+`$pX`MΣ
```

**Ungolfing**

```
         Implicit input s.
O        ord() every char in s.
4+       Add 4 to every ord in s.
`...`M   Map the following function over s. Variable m.
  $        Push str(m).
  pX       Discard the first char of str(m).
           Invariably this is a `1` and we get our ciphered m.
Σ        sum() everything to get one string.
         Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```python
lambda x:"".join(`ord(i)+4`[1:]for i in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxNCsIwEEDhqwyzalEEi6uAJ6mFpvkxU8aZEALW08dsuvt4i5d/NalMLT5fje1n8xYOg3jblWRYtfiBxstjne9miVqAgASOsZ2eMQVm/Wphj1d06sNbOXZazsluoTrKKZQedk3iglhcTC4kFWJftz8)

*Golfed to 49 bytes because .join will accept generators too*

*Golfed to 45 bytes because of lambdas*

*Golfed to 42 bytes because of switching to Python 2 and using ``` `` ``` (repr)*

**EXPLANATION:**

Uses the trick in the 05AB1E answer.

```python
lambda x:                               Declare a lambda accepting the string
    "".join(                            Join by the empty string
         `                              Repr (string representation)...
             ord(                       Unicode codepoint (A -> 65, a -> 97)
                 i                      The iterator in the for loop
             )
             + 4                        Added by 4
         `
         [1:]                           With the first character removed
    ) for i in x                        While a char i is in the string x
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

*Inspired by AdmBorkBork's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97898/80745).*

-6 bytes thanks @Julian

```powershell
-join($args|%{'{0:D2}'-f($_-96)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1ha4MwEIa/@ytCSFeFBi6pcbZQ6If9j@L0rC3BuOjowPrb3S2u6y5wkJfnubdzN/R9g9bK0nmcRX0YZ3l1lzYWhT/399W4HmH/pqe1rGNxkrssmZJ5iqJjHDGaTcx/bHdz3lachYhxyMEoTc/orTIqVxpSnjyE0lV4drZe8EUgDFIw8Eq4huwJF7ZrinccykvXoOcBVnQ5ow4FGowG2MIu/KnpKV5d05bYFv9aFFBLrlISDG1FcMLubMXGIIl@I/Crw3LAih2YOC2px/7TDhS8iJod@xByEf/mEj/@pGT/oHk0zd8)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1ha4MwEIa/@ytCSFeFBi6pcbZQ6If9j@L0rC3BuOjowPrb3S2u6y5wkJfnubdzN/R9g9bK0nmcRX0YZ3l1lzYWhT/399W4HmH/pqe1rGNxkrssmZJ5iqJjHDGaTcx/bHdz3lachYhxyMEoTc/orTIqVxpSnjyE0lV4drZe8EUgDFIw8Eq4huwJF7ZrinccykvXoOcBVnQ5ow4FGowG2MIu/KnpKV5d05bYFv9aFFBLrlISDG1FcMLubMXGIIl@I/Crw3LAih2YOC2px/7TDhS8iJod@xByEf/mEj/@pGT/oHk0zd8 "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") using splatting ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:"".join(f"{ord(j)-96:02}"for j in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQq4x9zY8iCoKEDmOYqCwnImREZ7f38lO9pKV3t7O5DmugacQxSkjk8JViKaphW/U0f@ikQISQoKmeS0iVHKE/meWWwhaV6j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 84 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][T    N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_char][T    T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    T   S S S S S N
_Push_96][T S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Dupe][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   S N
_If_neg_jump_to_Label_PRINT_0][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_DONE_WITH_PRINT_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_0][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_DONE_WITH_PRINT_0]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JUtbCsAwCPtOTuHVxlboQOjYBj2@TRXUvMzs99@@5zhbBM00WhoIAyCVR6YAGQtQksrIJLshXvX9XQYY0Zv7mOP1awE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start LOOP:
  Integer c = STDIN as character
  c = c - 96
  If(c < 10):
    Print 0 as integer to STDOUT
  Print c as integer to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,//$3 10\'96!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfX8VYwdAgRt3STFEpIzUnJ788vygnRYnr/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
,//$3 10\'96! / the solution
          96! / input modulo 96
    3 10\'    / convert to base 30ish
   $          / convert to string
,//           / flatten (,/) over (/)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 76 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(Join(,Text(Code(Mid(A1,Row(Indirect("1:"&Len(A1))),1))-96,"00"
```

Sheets will automatically add three closing parentheses when you exit the cell.
Input is in cell `A1`

`Indirect("1:"&Len(A1))` returns a range as tall as the input is long.
`Row(Indirect(~))` returns the row numbers, so it's a list of numbers from 1 to the input length.
`Mid(A1,Row(~),1)` returns each character from the input, one at a time.
`Code(Mid(~))-96` returns the ASCII code for each character, down-shifted so `a` = `1`.
`Text(Code(~),"00")` pads the result above to two digits.
`Join(,Text(~))` joins all those padded results without a delimiter.
`ArrayFormula(Join(~))` makes all the stuff above operate on arrays. Without, the result would just be the first padded alphabet code: `helloworld` would return `08`.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 27 bytes

```
 ,_9 @
%! 6-:
0    _
1_!/01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQSfeUsGBS1VRwUzXistAAQjiuQzjFfUNDP//z0jNyckvzy/KSQEA)

#### How it works

```
        Start at the first valid instruction, going right
,_96-:  Push a char, subtract 96, duplicate
@       If it's negative (EOF), turn left and terminate
        Otherwise it is positive. Turn right and follow the cycle
_10/!   Integer-divide by 10, pop and print as integer
_10%!   Modulo 10, pop and print as integer
        Re-enter the start of the program, looping until EOF
```

Comment: By replacing the second `_1` with `#` and some careful twisting of the code, this can be [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQSfe0oFLVVHBTJfLQMEw3opLWcGAS0lR////jNScnPzy/KKcFAA)

Comment: Oh, I realise that the `#` change did nothing, aince I have to add a no-op. It was just the rearrangement of the code that golfed bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
,/{$[1=#$x;"0",$x;$x]}'-96+0+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LRr1aJNrRVVqmwVjJQ0gFSKhWxteq6lmbaBtpcXGlKGak5OflKMEZ5flFOCoiXnJ+Smp6fk6YEAFobE00=)

Another function-less answer.

Explanation:

```
,/{$[1=#$x;"0",$x;$x]}'-96+0+       Main function.
                           0+       Convert each character to ASCII value.
                       -96+         Add with -96 for each of them
                      '             For each of the numbers
  {                  }              Execute a function that
   $[               ]               If
        $x                          The number converted to string
       #                            Length
     1=                             Is equal to 1
          ;"0",$x                   Then, pad "0" before the number
                 ;$x                Else, return the number converted to string
,/                                  Join
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 40 bytes

```
wi.hn$@'`-v
v o0'v$:a.<
v    <
>/ \K
  o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/788Uy8jT8VBPUG3jKtMId9AvUzFKlHPBsgGAhsuO32FGG8uBYX8//8zUnNy8svzi3JSAA)

## Flattened

```
wi.hn$@'`-.a:$v'0o>/o\K  Full solution
              >   ^      (additional redirections)

wi.hn$@               K  Where there are characters to read on the input
       '`-               Get the letter position in the alphabet
          .a:$v'0o       If it is less than 10, print a leading 0
                    o    Then print the number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5.5 bytes (11 nibbles)

```
+.$>>`p+4o
```

Another port of [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97864/95126).
(Converting to base-10 digits and dropping the first one comes-out half-a-byte (1 nibble) longer: `` +.$>>`@~+4o ``).

```
 .$             # map over each character in the input:
   >>           #  drop the first element of
     `P         #  the string representation of
         o      #  the ASCII value
       +4       #  plus 4
+               # and finally concatenate it all
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 51 Bytes

```
{it.collect{(((int)it-96)+"").padLeft(2,"0")}.join()}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 7 bytes

```
F.oOO`t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F.oOO%60t&input=ads)

```
F       -  for i in input:
 .o     -       ord(i)
   OO   -      ^ + 4
     `  -     str(^)
      t -    ^[1:]
        - sum(^)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy - 31 bytes

Groovy conversion of NumberKnot's solution in java:

```
{it.each{printf("%02d",it-96)}}
```

Example here using various options:

http://ideone.com/vd0dTX

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-98, 19 bytes

```
#@~'`-:a/'0+,a%'0+,
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 51

Dependency: `Foundation` for `String(format:_:)`

`{$0.utf8.map{String(format:"%02d",$0-96)}.joined()}` // where `$0` is `String`

### Usage:

[Test](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5815b6261503df5a9307a0b3)

`"codegolf".utf8.map{String(format:"%02d",$0-96)}.joined()`

or

`{$0.utf8.map{String(format:"%02d",$0-96)}.joined()}("codegolf")`

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 54 bytes

```
s=>String.Join("",s.Select(n=>(n<106?"0":"")+(n-96)));
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB / Octave, <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
@(s)sprintf('%02d',s-96)
```

### Explanation

1. `@(s)` denotes an anonymous function whose input is expected to be a string and stored in the variable `s`.
2. The ASCII code for the letter `a` is 97.  Therefore, subtracting the input string by 96 coalesces the string so that it becomes an array transforming the string into an array of numbers enumerated from 1 to 26, so we're now at `input('','s')-96`.
3. Using `sprintf` with the formatting specifier `%02d` takes the numbers in the array and ensures that there are 2 digits to output for each number.  The numbers are thus combined to a single string and we output a single string. We will also pad the first digit with a 0 in case there is only 1 digit in an array.

### Examples

```
>> f=@(s)sprintf('%02d',s-96)
>> f('helloworld')

ans =

08051212152315181204

>> f('codegolf')

ans =

0315040507151206

>> f('alphabetcipher')

ans =

0112160801020520030916080518

>> f('johncena')

ans =

1015081403051401
```

### Try it online!

[Try it here with ideone](http://ideone.com/BDTm1m).

Answer (score 0):

### [GolfSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/GolfSharp), 37 bytes

```
s=>s.s(n=>(n<106?"0":"")+(n-96)).j();
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 58 bytes

```
f(s)=>s.runes.map((t)=>'${t-96}'.padLeft(2,'0')).join('');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3BasMwDAbg@57Ch4FsugbJjbOUsj7BXsJNnCbFtY3jskPps2faLg3FICyhT39vc1mWQc7q6zhX@RbcXF1tkrLwAN7vZbtvHlAl23@7oUj9AQhKVZc4BQmgDsvV8k/d34RIeQpFDhJG5338idn3oMRGgNgeBbZoSPMzekeGWtJYM1@zLvbuHP2wQryKNRr8ZKKxeQHWp9GeXOmmNLq8YsQ5DScSajQacYf7/55zX05c4hg6F@wTE3JmSzUjw5X@wGP5BQ)

Other 58 bytes solution :

```
f(s)=>s.runes.map((t)=>(t>106?'0':'')+'${t-96}').join('');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3BisIwEAbg@z5FDguTIJaZ2NS6i91niW1qKzEpaZY9iM9eZ71YZCBMfvLl72zKy9LLWR2buUi/wc3F1U5SZg5kbgirH0D4AlAb@Lzl7aG6gyoucQySs@/lanlTtw8hpjSGLHsJg/M@/sXkO1BiI0BsG4E1GtI8Ru/IUE0aS@Zr1sbOnaPvV4ifYokG90w0Vm/A@mmwJ5fbcRpcWjHinoobCTUajbjDw/POvW9fXOIQWhfsCxNyZ00lI8Mn/YP78gA)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, <strike>197 191</strike> 181 bytes

```
|t:&String|->Option<String>{let a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";let mut o=String::new();for c in t.chars(){let n=a.find(c)?+1;if n<10{o.push('0');}o.push_str(&n.to_string());}Some(o)
```

Reduced number of bytes thanks to Jonathan Fretch. Code should be runnable at https://repl.it/repls/RightMiniFunctions

Reduced number of bytes again thanks to ASCII-only.

Comment: Can you not save some bytes by removing whitespace in `n < 10` or `n = a.find(c)`? Furthermore, would you mind adding a link to an online testing environment for ease of verification?

Comment: You should at least rename the function to a 1-character name. Also, lambdas (anonymous functions) are valid

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 43 bytes

```cs
n=>string.Concat(n.Select(c=>$"{c%32:D2}"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBi8IwEAXge35FCIoJdMuiN7W97CoIwoIuePEyTqcmS5iUNNVD6W@vope9vMfje9h@YOvGbce4blN0fM3eVdbFyEX5HvlXYISkOT@SJ0wai3Kiepwu5svv@aCMGVeiDpEArb5BlCAdyx3nB4LqN2y40iY/Nt4lPTvzzJhenKJLtHdMWu246ZJcyv5zUBmY1X/76dITX3ZmldUazPMwjJa8D@KV9xB9JTBUdA2@FuAbCxdK6BpLUfwFy0gMDw)

## Alternative taking in a `List<char>`, 36 bytes

```cs
n=>n.ForEach(c=>Write($"{c%32:D2}"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwEETv@gohUqKF1pT0ZseGQlMIBAptoJdcNmu5UhC7Rlbag/G3u0l66WUub94wNDzQEOZnykF4vQtDXpPH1DRdPXPdcPEqaYPkLdXNZwrZ2YUZ6e5pVb6sJgMwV6qT5K6Nb0wadWC95eLdYbuXDbcWio8@hmyXB14CjOo2sgvsrNlyf8661OPjZO4Rqj9mzds5X0CpDVSdxWIv11sWoPrnHvhC1TR7F6OoW/5Iiq0iad2XxE5h7D0eXabQe5fUSTyTY/wF)

Comment: `List<char>` is a valid way to take in a string

Comment: I know, I just thought of the alternative after my first solution so I put it after it

Comment: 32 bytes with `SelectMany` (but returns an `IEnumerable<char>`).

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-m`, 8 bytes

```
c +4 s Å
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YyArNCBzIMU=&input=ImNvZGVnb2xmIgoKLW0=)

Answer (score 0):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 112 bytes

I could save 8 bytes on line 2 if STR$() didn't insist on including a leading space.

```
1 INPUT S$:FOR I=1 TO LEN(S$):A=ASC(MID$(S$,I,1))-96:IF A<10 THEN O$=O$+"0"
2 O$=O$+MID$(STR$(A),2):NEXT:PRINT O$
```

Sample output

```
? alphabetcipher
0112160801020520030916080518
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

In GolfScript converting to a character is unneccecary because strings are character arrays.

```
{4+''+1>}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9pEW11d29CuVvX//8ScgozEpNSS5MyCjNQiAA)

### Explanation

```
{       }% # Foreach over the implicit codepoint list
 4+        # Add 4 to every item of the list
   ''+     # Convert to a string
      1>   # Filter out all characters after the 1st character,
           # Including the 1st character
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 39 bytes

The usual +4 approach.

```erlang
f(X)->[tl(integer_to_list(I+4))||I<-X].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDADA3Wc4JUidnETc/YEgUkRTDcRWYsDFv1dvPlJZ4u7oXpUvy0UOMKLrJxPgaLSTekte@DYYqgbxfYfOjXOdz4UjTPN/ObXhUTaCAOVBIulJKluJWOcP)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 99 bytes

```powershell
([char[]]"$args"|%{"0$((@(65..90|%{[char]$_})-join'').indexof($_.tostring().toupper())+1)"})-join''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyM6OSOxKDo2VkklsSi9WKlGtVrJQEVDw0HDzFRPz9IAyAeriFWJr9XUzcrPzFNX19TLzEtJrchP01CJ1yvJLy4pysxL19AEMksLClKLNDQ1tQ01leDK////7wG0K78cAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 55 bytes

```python
N-6
Count i while _/5 {
Write _/10+39
Write _%10+48
N-6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/99P14zLOb80r0QhU6E8IzMnVSFe31Shmiu8KLMExDY00Da2hPFUgTwTCy6gnv//M1JzcvLL84tyUgA)

#### Explanation

```python
# Read a character, subtract 6 from its charcode, and store in the accumulator
N-6
# Loop while the character was not newline (i.e. the accumulator is >= 5)
Count i while _/5 {
  # Subtract 90 from the accumulator, divide by 10, and output as a digit
  Write (_-90)/10+48
  # Output the accumulator mod 10 as a digit
  Write _%10+48
  # Read the next character
  N-6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Knight, 49 bytes

```
;;;;=y""=xP=i 0W>+1Lx=i+1i=y+yG+4A Gx-i 1 1 1 2Oy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKWyNXxJJcFVbNjJFskBRRyALyeUD@BIhy3hqZdknybwsYf96rrvnRSPb5C53S6osa@bpnu5nerp7nKh3G0XfX4k0SpbjeC8vxmL@ejqs2yOJuKkMRcXjIl4BZSK9rQwVYiYx43gi0pglCUvm6S191M3ox7NP75lXvl5@vGB@@fqPgwu2W74enb1jv5SvF5@YV4KPTi8t7NmnUwv66ez9weXfnZwzBz@a7E/vb9zMHlzCsnIymoYZa/NSwEaBrUbFcMh2y7mzw884mcIkefSN4fe9vRUMLkMYdBMwScIRWMG8PT8/JRB@7JOTffTNMuTiWAJA3rL1LkyWMedX6YjX6@QH7MrVKLhoHJ4fOd8H8Bc8NhrBw4dAMPfzsOOdPgSi44ngsfN43Nk9YMcPPcE8@uefP37nINcYSFVt0BWHMxag0kG9DisvwiyPHc6e6jWRFkwM6jUYJSu6rD1ZphGMkHAE78Vs0c0X6ZU/Cp7crvsMOmoC1BEeni4OvHmD6sWC3U9FEeeLMIrrNfiexA6Mg7gjzeiyxnVxnV5PrjP29Hw1cnj/VYOTKTUxYY6xNmCtVy3OpAo9ugWj1ykMdzpyBOysxUke2wPP0pxoGke/s8k8Y@lydhNnubKHOSIfi1tRaK2wOrrjdY1H8tlmnss6rK0s73Q467GW24Il0FLBWRYXyyxlOm6kGIXOYNWGuzAT4U0SayvAiGR@H2dOBOtpQ9i3b0wbF9FbRER8aXFFj9jgugi8LuxRYIZXrMOTqCIWIOl4uXBwS5nitMfgbd1gmRdyqU2acd1qlTY1WnLTQBg8MEYxUAJ5BL6DZYswL1gxjUFZmBUAVhvQ1ozihkYcPdHGWsfrRWPh0@O00bWSDDIfQ7cQ8xTMxoh1R2BapBnJl4sFEs51VOkRm347/oB2i2zUoUN5kUIcQ07DyFWWS1Y@tszBlwNHOID5rY95Dc3UQUYpUbrqoN1oapgk88jZdbseRwdx2DhBDqbLJAmzR9vRcn8urO350DKW0YJKfpmuSNMSHi6hksImTw8O3777@tvW6a/nlsO22huxUa@/rnerovj45PIFjUWckcowHbN/LUP9imrv7CV21peQBBy3DBcnG7gg4d2qcBXzTKkyW6a4QwOVl9vFPHd0rqQDAKFdiIjR7M1ycuXvjpQdcqOblB6MAfkCjlUxcQAK/m8nybih8w7VpS4qWVUAh8IokBVPrl/B7TFvp@onOo@xuM8aRbaMGxCDZhxDEsYnIWQQnGhgZDVKEtBP9F2VJqLjy9v5PIGZmyoDL/pauvUjh9o/75Ft5s2amQnamP6lNkLQFvMkcWxTu8ztQoX4H0xO10zGKvz@4MNZF2uxDDR4PbnyXNeFcAJX4FW/5eKP@EvB8DGwYtTyFhmAty5@@PS5E3i6pGOGw6qOD/r05WMHAEcnp4dtNoHkOKiZ0FbrYRqOwkU3iVPqACyudOckOYNz9xIZq4JYm7C0YcFxBPUSUIv3iIsBFBWBkyZvRLPFyg4QSWJUphCkSYxwmfxeFNHUaQMza40WcMTUX4R1qnXQ6jNcRQICJBRbNcjCvElOKfWqWayELB9QFS4R1JEWGZYuakqvRvypDDNooCi3y4UvYOGq7gwynsOb7sME/0rkB0CCVsnRbVwk0E86TdrLJu4QlsixSPlATByH9hMbgmiaoS1diFPO5TYH7mCjrfDg1AbI9Q7lerJzxGygCBloe5EklTtLK9@W/ki8mXlXzqCkTbHBfAUMRgPEX7CYL@LUsRbuNrIGtQpgVTCTlRLiMfDd3V9oXDUXjuxIJmD6GJ2CFg5Ctov9HcChd6A3XAOW1uHlwCDrBNQK4YkFJFd0gx5ai6hGDe2A@XbPUtJYevIbeBI/QBuHp33Nz63KrtO1YQsz2RrwdC08YJWkyosF/7XVV33ihkA2mU9VoMYZtcUO1iCui9BwuMvLxnItHWrRS2oOne0cBauHYV0Y6ITWx14XMilvlFA9geUlDlOl9qUSpmqWvQMqtygWzksW8GDIiw@SJvezQh1rNumu1eshdCTb3Gtqt2varO3X7RzsceCNM33UMsv8ZZHr3TcxIXs9aVDHGER5EvIlpmQMLWt7ZDddq@62vLgiGvp@pmPJl3uO/S8dBrkBhMJhPOWB9tLnm0M1Cgv9UF2n1ylp4vo76uLQjXbpWagcofzqrUWnFe3YqlftlULtcnc2sLBanjfw0F7jQe7rJhZmG1xrEyawlZAA1CCHMmTQuoZLHoIGvR7pU0RRyVzdaMloUTn9b35IzJvNxGz/UGh7s9A/ic2KQ/LqQGO@7eVA0S5ZD1jPMywTFqj34Jz1PDhjng32fxK9B@mxgg0ChNK6fT3iasqJaH/oKq59Tu1KOyD@66sHgibJFbgjUILFEgPf8cowjbO4lbN0Dj20SAqRsvvwEXhj4zncSYv4Ns5AZjFP47QQId4i4CTP2X3MpuFdDEClCOEFm4XpEsLn8TWOonc3yDhQQUzky6TAHw1ocZPwNKRnY/SSK5TZcgayoh71vYx0XzbEwPYqKJfu52GCtfERvE7HSTxmX0uzvxotT/hNNmbWIqUzQ1TW6@l3TvCagrYt059NHtyjYF0pfJj0KnkxqGbFfWYf/j37GKBoX/0k12QSsM8qjSINdpmVDVGHKyV1yfVlHUDsVgDVxuqChnAoMbTm43mfzeJZtMAwS9nw6/7/68rwL3BlqF3Z2uBLoHxRruy/zL5cdYPJOL3PKgDfIHxdQLc22Vm@GPd05rEVGPOaZfpDXzbVhn1bUqUSI//tv5FXOchSY@QHrb6NrrS5q9igzLrV6Z@@yOjetrzJIK5Wuc2YVEgY1DgKKtJWmkQJRHQ6Rkya/Bnck7962Y1mxTtm9y5K7KTatSPUkt/3@zsWLcfyyhBYHVbHLkDrd6RUXTy65izsVBraS0n0itLBasnzN5W8HW76AN9I79Lgf2iI0DB84lZEpvk37ZDdG/ngIa7a8bBJogZBxr@cpAchOuokwOrjeBJCkgTPdIcpUpgUY/oRKYwKKFOt7aiFPSeOcPbCLRaVmRoI3aD6IWEWihSbVRZmt1GXlLbb8P2O489VdL/E/@FxXLKmeo17/j6NweH7eZaM/w0)

What a mess.

Ungolfed:

```
; = y ""
; = x PROMPT
; = i 0
; WHILE (> (+ 1 LENGTH (x)) (= i (+ 1 i))
    = y (+ y (GET (+ 4 (ASCII (GET x (- i 1) 1))) 1 2))
: OUTPUT y
```

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 57 bytes

```
(over(display(pop(number->string(+(char->integer x)4)))))
```

Everyone came up with the +4 ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
{i4+s1>}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/b8600S72NCuVvV/rZWbdbRSRmpOTn55flFOipKCUnJ@Smp6fk4akJmYU5CRmJRakpxZkJFaBBTIys/IS07NS1SKrY53U1KwtVNQitHWrlX10/oPAA)

A function taking a string as input. Port of many other answers.

## Explanation

```
{      }% # for each value in the input
 i        # convert it into a number
  4+      # add 4 to it
    s     # convert it to a string
     1>   # drop the first character
```

A version which isn't a port, for fun:

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
{'`-sYTe[}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/b9aPUG3ODIkNbpW9X@tlZt1tFJGak5Ofnl@UU6KkoJScn5Kanp@ThqQmZhTkJGYlFqSnFmQkVoEFMjKz8hLTs1LVIqtjndTUrC1U1CK0dauVfXT@g8A)

## Explanation

```
{        }% # map the following across the input
 '`-        # subtract the codepoint of '`', 96, from each value
    s       # convert to a string
       e[   # and pad the left with
      T     # 0s to length
     Y      # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `JB`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
4+ıṘḣ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0kpeTUuyCpaUlaboWq0y0j2x8uHPGwx2LlxQnJRdDhResSM5PSU3Pz0mD8AE)

Port of Adnan's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
4+ıṘḣ  # Implicit input
       # Convert to codepoints
4+     # Add four
  ı    # Map:
   Ṙ   #  Convert to string
    ḣ  #  Remove the first item
       # Join the list
       # Implicit output
```