# Encode the backwards alphabet cipher

Tags: code-golf, alphabet, cipher

Given a string of text that contains lowercase letters, encode it as follows: (I will be using `abcdef`)

- First, encode the [alphabet cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97859/encode-the-alphabet-cipher), but this time, 0-indexed. `000102030405`
- Reverse it. `504030201000`
- Loop through the string.

  - If the next two digits together are 25 or smaller, encode those two numbers. `5` `04` `03` `02` `01` `00` `0`
  - Otherwise, encode one number. `f` `e` `d` `c` `b` `a` `a`
- Join. `fedcbaa`

### Test cases

```
abcdef                          fedcbaa
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz      fyxwvucjsrqponmlktihgfedcbaa
helloworld                      dbromylloha
ppcg                            gcfpb
codegolf                        fboqedema
programmingpuzzlesandcodegolf   fboqedemddkiobpzuzqdscmkhqerpb
```

[Encoder (not golfed)](https://repl.it/EQXU/3)

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I get different answers for some of the test cases.  For example, `codegolf` becomes `0214030406141105`, reversing to `5011416040304120`, split as `5`,`01`,`14`,`16`,`04`,`03`,`04`,`12`,`0` turning into `fboqedema` instead of `fbobgedema` as you have.

Comment: @GabrielBenamy Fixed. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @xigoi `cc` actually encodes to `uu`.

Comment: @OliverNi Sorry, I forgot about the leading zeros. An actual example of why this isn't reversible is that both `qx` and `qcd` encode to `dcgb`.

Comment: @xigoi Ah yep, you're right. Not a great challenge tbh, but i wrote it a long time ago so

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>126</s> 125 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s.replace(/./g,c=>(parseInt(c,36)+90+'').slice(1))].reverse().join``.replace(/2[0-5]|[01]?./g,c=>(+c+10).toString(36))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZE9T8MwEIb3/opusZXUTUEgEErZkJgZSwX@uDhOnNix89WI/14soCoD5ZZbnve5011JB@q5U7ZbNUbAMc@OPtvuCCGeOLCackBrspYJz7bIUufhuekQT65vcXyfxlGEidcqQBuM9yExQEAQJqVRzfv7WXG1S1c3@49dutk/nnQxjzcpJp156ZxqJApOfHxYOGh75QBFuQ92B1Q8KQ0oTaK@y@@iBL0lE86201mOXscYL@OvFtwBoAkLCDeNNxqINhLliOIsYziMoIwLyJcXKwfBGaWLb04Wqqx03RjbOt/1wzgd5h/uMI1Dz0vvWmuaWledKuQpXIDWZjROi7@HCOZMfQhMQRfWcrn8pyTPLVvw8B9p9MXFc2ZaEFAHnzPS0boOR7X9PGvwtBG/4idSiEoZZud@boXndVW04Cz7BA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 73 + 2 = 75 bytes

Run with the `-lp` flag

```
s/./sprintf"%02d",-97+ord$&/eg;$_=reverse;s/2[0-5]|[01]?[0-9]/chr$&+97/eg
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 107 bytes

```hs
g.reverse.(>>=tail.show.(+3).fromEnum)
g(a:b:c)|r<-read[a,b],r<26=['a'..]!!r:g c
g(a:b)=[a..]!!49:g b
g e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco9T8MwEADQPb/iGiE1EYmHgpCI6m5sbIwhw8U5OxH@0jkBKeK3Y6p2fXozpi@yNjtcPEiYQgEQt/Vj5XcPD6ChjBwMo3OLN3Hbd0sJ/aTCRCZYXRZafmYjmL6JE4nqcpErLlakOfyI6vGpFpqDe/ObqwtTYTd2qv7lc8uEU4/NODR8Pr3I/ohHIYbDgTsD6j5r2ePNnl@vOBYGSFLOf0pbNCm3KsZ/)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>31</s> 26 bytes

-5 bytes after taking a look at [Lynn's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231228/64121).

```
Ç3+€¦JR[Ð2£₂‹>DŠ£Aè?.$DõQ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU8AsP9vc2FiaWX//8OHMyvigqzCpkpSW8OQMsKj4oKC4oC5PkTFoMKjQcOoPy4kRMO1USP//3Byb2dyYW1taW5ncHV6emxlc2FuZGNvZGVnb2xm)

```python
Ç                     # codepoints of the input
 3+                   # add 3 to each (a->100, b->101, ...)
   €¦                 # remove the leading "1" from each number/string 
     J                # join into a single string
      R               # and reverse the string
                                                                          STACK
[                     # infinite loop
 Ð                    # push 2 copies of the current remaining string s   s, s, s
  2£                  # take the first two chars of s                     s[:2], s, s
    ₂‹                # are they (as a number) less than 26 (0 or 1)      s[:2]<26, s, s
      >D              # add 1 and duplicate the result                    (s[:2]<26)+1, (s[:2]<26)+1, s, s
        Š             # rotate the top three items on the stack           (s[:2]<26)+1, s, (s[:2]<26)+1, s
         £            # take the first or two first characters from s     s[:(s[:2]<26)+1], (s[:2]<26)+1, s
          Aè          # index with those into the alphabet                
            ?         # and print the result without a trailing newline
             .$       # remove the characters from s                      s[(s[:2]<26)+1:]
               DõQ#   # if s is now empty, exit the loop
```